# GCM, Upstream messaging , how does the server side application receive that?

Tags: java, google-cloud-messaging

I am using GCM with android on client side and java on server side.
In case of downstream messaging, the broadcast receiver receives the messages and then processing is done.
I want to know how the upstream messaging is implemented on server side application. how the server side app is informed of such messages? 
Do i need to have a persistent connection with google servers from my server application?